# How to copy an object so that original does not change while changing copied one

Tags: java

I want to write a method in java which gives `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` (say *result*) from `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`(say *original*) without changing the original one. So I have to first store *original* in some variable but i dont find a proper or easy way

for ex. I want to remove a certain object (Integer) from *original* 
this is how i am coding

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> rmv(Integer a,ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> original){

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    //storing original to other variable

    for(int i=0;i<original.size();i++){
        ArrayList<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int j=0;j<original.get(i).size();j++){
            temp.add(original.get(i).get(j));
        }
        result.add(temp);
    }

    // not so important here
    for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++){
        result.get(i).remove(a);            
    }
    return result;
}
```

plz suggest me if there is any shortcut method

Comment: Look into the keywords `clone object java`.

Comment: @hexafraction clone of ArrayList returns a shallow copy, so cloning the outer ArrayList doesn't meet the OP's requirements. You could clone each of the inner ArrayLists, though, since they contain an immutable objects (Integers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is close to the best that you can do in java:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
for(ArrayList<Integer> list : result){
    result.add(list.clone());
}
```

Also for future reference, what you are doing is called a "deep copy". Search that term for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
for(int i=0;i<original.size();i++){
    ArrayList<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    temp.addAll(original.get(i));
    result.add(temp);
}
```

Alternately, you can use [clone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone%28%29) :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
for(int i=0;i<original.size();i++){
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = (ArrayList<Integer>) original.get(i).clone();
    result.add(temp);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the addAll still hold a reference to the original ArrayLists in the ArrayList<ArrayList<>> ? Clone will definitely work.

Comment: @Hari addAll `Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list`. I'm not adding the inner ArrayLists to the copy of the outer ArrayList. I'm adding the Integers of each inner ArrayList to the new copy of that inner ArrayList. While the Integer instances in both lists would be the same, Integer is immutable, so it makes no difference.